# Connect a server to another through VPN

Tags: security, vpn

I need to access a LDAP directory from server A. However the directory is hosted on server B, which I can only access from server A using a VPN connection.

My question is: how stable and secured would it be to permanently connect server A to server B? Would there be a risk that the password of my VPN account could be compromised? is that a common way to access resources protected in such a way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which kind of VPN do you use? If you use something with certificates your own VPN account password is not in case. Everything else depends on how secure you thing your VPN is.

Comment: It's an L2TP/IPSec VPN, I use my username and password to connect... Mainly my question is: if someone gain access to the server, would it be possible for them to see my password?

Comment: After connection is established your password should not stay in memory. But I think for persistent connections the connection should made by a service and not by a logged in user.